# On number of ordered pairs with given lcm and an interesting sequence of fractions

Tags: number-theory

For a positive integer $n,$ let $f(n)$ denote the number of ordered pairs with lcm $n$. Since the total number of ordered pairs from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ is $n^2$ it seems interesting to to see how the sequence $\left\langle \frac{f(n)}{n^2} \right\rangle$ behaves. I did some simulations and it seems the sequence should converge to zero but I am not analytically sure. Can somebody kindly help me out?

Comment: Since this (long-winded) response is (in my opinion) inappropriate as an *answer*, I am *commenting.*  Initially, I thought that if the prime factorization of $n = \prod_{i=1}^r \,p_i^{(\alpha_i)},$ then the question would navigate towards considering $n = a\times b,$ with $a$ = the product of some subset of the $r$ primes, with each prime $p_i$ raised to the exponent $\alpha_i.$ ...See next comment.

Comment: If $n = \prod_{i=1}^r \,p_i^{(\alpha_i)}$, the number of ordered pairs with lcm.$n $ can be shown to be $\prod_{i=1}^r \{(2.\alpha_i+1)}$

Comment: However, I now think that this *navigation* is **oversimplified.**  With $n = a\times b,$ a given prime $p_i$ can be *shared* by both $a$ and $b.$  That is, $p_i^{(\beta_i)} | a$ and $p_i^{(\gamma_i)} | b$, with $\alpha_i = \max(\beta_i, \gamma_i).$  This **sharing** of prime factors throws a monkey wrench into my intuition and prevents me from trying to use my intuition to move forward on the problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, re my reaction to your comment: the problem is too complicated for me, so I am forced to (currently) have **no opinion** re your comment.  By the way, I upvoted; interesting problem.

Comment: $f(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n^2$. It's tabulated at http://oeis.org/A048691 with links to the literature. The number of divisors of $n^2$ is trivially bounded above by $2n-1$, so the quotient you ask about certainly goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  much simpler than my approach.  Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Ross, I thought about that, but I'm not sure how simple it is to show that $f(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n^2$. I don't see a one-one correspondence between divisors $d$ of $n^2$, and pairs $(a,b)$ with least common multiple $n$. I could use the multiplicativity of $f$ to get the result, but then I'd have to prove the multiplicativity, and that takes a bit of doing.

Answer (score 2):

First, for any prime $p$ the ordered pairs are $(1,p), (p,1), (p,p)$, so we have $f(p)=3, \frac{f(p)}{p^2}=\frac {3}{p^2}$ which goes to $0$ for large $p$, so $0$ is an accumulation point.  To show it is the limit, we need to show the highest values also go to $0$.

Consider $f(n)$ for $n$ the power of a prime, $n=p^k$.  We have $f(n)=2k+1$ because one of the elements of the ordered pair must be $p^k$ while the other can be any power of $p$ from $0$ to $k$.  Now note that your function $f(n)$ is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).  If $n=ab$ with $a,b$ coprime, $f(n)=f(a)\cdot f(b)$.  If the prime factorization of $n$ is $n=p^aq^br^c$ we have $f(n)=(2a+1)(2b+1)(2c+1)$ because you can distribute the powers of each prime independently.  You need $a,b,c$ powers of each prime in one of the two factors, then $0$ to the maximum in the other.

The $n$ that are maxima so far of $f(n)$ will be similar to the [highly composite numbers](https://oeis.org/A002182) but will have more large primes and less factors of $2$ because adding a new prime triples the number of pairs instead of only doubling the number of factors.  For example $30$ is a new maximum of $f(n)$ with $27$ pairs, while it only has $8$ factors which is no more than $24$ has.

A rough way to see that $\frac {f(n)}{n^2}$ converges to $0$ is to consider the primorials, the products of the first $k$ primes.  These have $3^k$ ordered pairs, which is a lot, but they are not the smallest numbers with that many ordered pairs-you want more small factors than that.  The primorials are roughly $k^k$, so we are asking about $\frac {3^k}{k^{2k}}$, which goes to zero.  I am sure that the same thing will happen with the maxima of $f(n)$ but don't know how to demonstrate it.

Comment: *betraying the limit of my intuition*: If you deem it worthwhile, please *addendum/edit* your answer to demonstrate that $f(n)$ is **multiplicative.**

Comment: Please explain the case of $ n = p^{k}$. It's divisors will be $ 1, p,p^2,...,p^k$ which are total k+1 in number. In that case how can f(n) be 2k + 1? Shouldn't it be (k+1)? Other multiples of $p$ can only have a non trivial gcd with$ p^{k}$ but cannot yield the LCM as $p^k$

Comment: @Laxmi:  You can have $(p^k,p^m)$ with $m$ ranging from $0$ to $k$, which is $k+1$ of them.  You can also have $(p^m,p^k)$ with $m$ in the same range, making a total of $2k+2$.  We have counted $(p^k,p^k)$ twice, so the final answer is $2k+1$

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Got it. Thanks for explaining.